# Getting false while executing rs.next() in my code

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

rs.next() is returning false while there is data in table. Using oracle as database.

```
try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from users where uname=? and pass=?");
        ps.setString(1, uname);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        out.println(rs.next());
        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println("<font color='green'>Successfull login</font>");
        } else { 
            out.println(uname+"  "+pass);
            out.println("<font color='red'>Wrong username or password.</font>");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: remove this statement `out.println(rs.next());` , then it will work fine

Comment: when **if block** was not getting executed then i added `out.println(rs.next());`to know boolean value.

Comment: If you want to log the result of `rs.next()` and you want to use that value later you must assign it to a value first and log that value. Add some info about the SQL table and its columns. Maybe the pass is being stored hashed (as it should be) and you're searching its plain value?

Comment: The value is not hashed, it's plain value. @Pelocho

Comment: @Prashant put `out.println(rs.next());` after **IF ELSE block**

Comment: Did you check that the SQL query is correctly executed in SQL Plus? Is this the only query that fails or every query fails? That would mean the problem is in another part of your code

Comment: @Asif.Ali, my concern is that `rs.next()` should return true because there some data in table. I inserted `out.println(rs.next());` just for inspection purpose. This `out.println(rs.next());` should also print true in first time as well. Even after removing `out.println(rs.next()); , expected output is not coming.

Comment: @Pelocho, Yea the query is correct.

Comment: check you input names inside your form, that must be same as your `request.getParameter();`

Comment: does you parameters have special characters e.g. in different language than english? if not are you sure you test it on same database?

Answer (score 1):

when you call

```
out.println(rs.next());
```

It move to next result and then second time call it the next result is called

If you have 1 result in SQL it will return false in the if statement you call rs.next()

Comment: after commenting rs.next(), still if block is not getting executed.

Answer (score -1):

You are using ResultSet object resource in:

> out.println(rs.next());

So to reuse it you have to add

> rs.previous();

after

> out.println(rs.next());

like

```
try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from users where uname=? and pass=?");
        ps.setString(1, uname);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        out.println(rs.next());
        rs.previous();
        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println("<font color='green'>Successfull login</font>");
        } else { 
            out.println(uname+"  "+pass);
            out.println("<font color='red'>Wrong username or password.</font>");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `rs.previous()` doesn't work with a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` (which is the default) result set, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Yes it is throwing exception when i used `rs.previous()`

Comment: If you have to use `rs.previous();` then write `ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from users where uname=? and pass=?",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`